# how to make incremental value in hierarchal array in Php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, increment, hierarchy

Hi guys I was wondering how can I add a incremental all elements? Because as of now I am not sure where can I include the "inc" in all elements

Ex:

```
MY_ARRAY = (
[id] => 4
[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 21
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 22
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 26
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Using these code:

```
$in = MY_ARRAY
function generateArray($in, $parent = 0){

        foreach ($in as $key => $value) {
            if(is_numeric($key)){
                $in = $value;
                $out[$key] = $this->generateArray($in, $parent);
            }else{
                $out[$key]=$value;
                if($key=="id"){
                    $out['p_id'] = $parent;
                    $parent=$value;
                }elseif($key=="children"){
                    $in = $value;
                    $out[$key] = $this->generateArray($in, $parent);
                }
            }
        }   
      return $out;
    }
```

Will give me this output, not including the [inc].

```
[id] => 4
[P_id] => 0
[inc] => 1
[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [P_id] => 4
                [inc] => 2
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 21
                                [P_id] => 18
                                [inc] => 3
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 22
                                [P_id] => 18
                                [inc] => 4
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
                [P_id] => 4
                [inc] => 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [P_id] => 4
                [inc] => 6
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 26
                                [P_id] => 20
                                [inc] => 7
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Now I'm not sure where and how can I include the [inc] or the incremental value of each element in the array using my code above.

Need really help here guys...

Comment: Is this possible? because I tried to add counter everywhere in the code but I have no luck.... need helps guys....